# HAProxy unable to redirect to HTTPS when terminating

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I wanted to setup HAProxy for two servers - one with passthroug one with termination. I was able to do it with no previous experience of HAProxy, but I am unable to make HTTPS redirect for the terminating one - I get 502. Here is the config:

```
#Upgrades the passthrough and check for Let's Encrypt
frontend http_front
    bind :80
    option forwardfor
    acl host_s1 hdr(host) -i s1.example.com
    acl path_le path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    redirect scheme https code 301 if host_s1 !path_le
    use_backend acmetool if path_le
    default_backend http-back

#Handles the passthrough and loopsback to itself for other domains
frontend passthrough
    mode tcp
    bind :443
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
    use_backend service1 if { req_ssl_sni -i s1.example.com }
    default_backend https-back

#Loopback to handle the termination domains
frontend https-front
    bind 127.0.0.1:8443 ssl crt s2.example.com.pem
    option forwardfor
    reqdel X-Forwarded-Proto
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    use_backend service2 if { req_ssl_sni -i s2.example.com }
    default_backend service2

#returns for second pass from HTTP
backend http-back
    server https-front 127.0.0.1:8443

#returns for second pass from HTTPS
backend https-back
    mode tcp
    server https-front 127.0.0.1:8443

backend service1
    mode tcp
    server service1 127.0.0.1:8888

backend service2
    #redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    server server2 server2:80

backend acmetool
    server acmetool 127.0.0.1:81
```

Not sure if I need those `reqdel/reqadd` in `https-front`. Or if I have to do `tcp-request` again on the second pass for HTTPS.

Uncommenting the redirect on the backend does not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with some [help from the HAProxy community](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/haproxy-unable-to-redirect-to-https-when-terminating/).

Here is the final setup with updated names to better reflect the logic behind each one:

```
#Upgrades to HTTPS unless it's Let's Encrypt
frontend http
    bind :80
    option forwardfor
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ path_beg -i /.well-known/acme-challenge/ }
    default_backend acmetool

#Handles the passthrough and loopsback for termination
frontend passthrough
    mode tcp
    bind :443
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
    use_backend service1 if { req_ssl_sni -i s1.example.com }
    default_backend loopback

#Handles the termination domains on second pass
frontend termination
    bind 127.0.0.1:8443 ssl crt s2.example.com.pem
    option forwardfor
    reqdel X-Forwarded-Proto
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    use_backend service2 if { ssl_fc_sni -i s2.example.com }
    default_backend service2

#Loopback for second pass
backend loopback
    mode tcp
    server https-front 127.0.0.1:8443

backend service1
    mode tcp
    server service1 127.0.0.1:8888

backend service2
    server server2 server2:80

backend acmetool
    server acmetool 127.0.0.1:81
```